# PCL library version in ROS

Tags: pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm wondering what the version of PCL library in my ROS is.
For example, currently PCL is 1.5.1 updated on 2012.02.22, then what is it for my
PCL? And where can I check out these version information?
Also, how can I update my PCL in ROS when the standalone PCL library is updated?

Thanks for answering.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30944/pcl-library-version-in-ros/) by [Mchaiiann](https://answers.ros.org/users/1388/mchaiiann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2012-03-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Please checkout the latest version of perception_pcl_electric_unstable at
http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/

Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The general policy is for each ROS distribution to depend on the most recent PCL library available at the time it is released. For API stability, that will remain fixed until the next release.

Since PCL changes faster than ROS, that library version will not remain the latest for long. If it gets far enough behind, an *unstable* PCL may be published for those needing new features and not requiring API stability.

Beginning in Fuerte, ROS uses `rosdep` for the system PCL. That should make it easier to use newer versions as they come out.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mchaiiann](https://answers.ros.org/users/1388/mchaiiann/) on 2012-04-01**:
Hi, is it correct to check out the version information by
sudo apt-cache policy ros-electric-perception-pcl?
Thanks!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-02**:
That should work. Mine says 1.0.2 for Electric right now. If you need something more recent, see answer from @karthik.

**Comment by [Mchaiiann](https://answers.ros.org/users/1388/mchaiiann/) on 2012-04-02**:
Thanks. Mine says 1.0.2 and I'm using Electric, too. But at this page http://ros.org/wiki/electric it states that PCL in Electric is v1.1, thus I'm wondering which one make sense.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-04-02**:
Mine one is also 1.0.2. Maybe, it also depends on ubuntu version, I'm on Lucid anyway..

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-02**:
It will be the same for all up-to-date ROS Electric packages. I'm using Oneiric.

**Comment by [Mchaiiann](https://answers.ros.org/users/1388/mchaiiann/) on 2012-04-08**:
Thanks, and I'm using ROS Electric on Maverick.